# Setting permissions in ZipArchive

Tags: php, macos, unix, zip, php-ziparchive

I have a Zip file. I open it with ZipArchive php library, and add a dir and a file in it. When I extract it with ubuntu's default unarchiver everything works as expected. But when I extract it with any unarchiver on OS X Snow Leopard (tried with the default one, Keka and The Unarchiver) the new directory's permissions are 700. The expected permissions are 755.

So, here is the original zip:

```
DIRECTORY
a.txt
b.txt
```

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$file = 'example.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($file, ZipArchive::CREATE);
  if ($res === TRUE) {

    $zip->addEmptyDir('DIRECTORY/NEW_DIR');
    $zip->addFromString('DIRECTORY/NEW_DIR/c.txt', 'hellooo');
    $zip->close();
  }
  else {
    print 'error';
  }
```

And the result is:

```
DIRECTORY -> NEW_DIR -> c.txt
a.txt
b.txt
```

wich is correct, but the permissions of NEW_DIR directory is 700 (drwx------) instead of 755 if I extract it under osx. How to fix it?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's the zipinfo about the files in my zip:

```
$ zipinfo -l test.zip 
(..)
drwxr-xr-x  3.0 unx        0 bx        0 stor 13-Dec-11 17:43 DIRECTORY/
-rw-r--r--  3.0 unx      533 tx      327 defN  3-Nov-11 01:50 a.txt
-rw-r--r--  3.0 unx    91669 tx    32044 defN  3-Nov-11 01:09 b.txt
-rw----     0.0 fat        0 b-        2 defN 13-Dec-11 18:12 DIRECTORY/new_dir/
-rw----     0.0 fat        7 b-        9 defN 14-Dec-11 10:30 DIRECTORY/new_dir/c.txt
```

Comment: Interesting update: the origin of you items is stored as "Unix file system" or "Windows FAT" :-?

Comment: I'm using a Snow Leopard, I think it's hfs+.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the necessary security privileges, you could do something along the lines of

```
<?php
    exec("chmod -R 755 /directory/new_dir");
```

Comment: Thank you, but in the actual application the zip will not be extracted on the server. The user can download it, and if she uses OSX she will meet the permission problem described above, and she will have to manually fix it, wich is not user friendly.